# LINQ / Xpath query for ungrouped and repeated XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, xquery

I am new to .NET and I am having some trouble implementing queries in LINQ to XML.

I have a XML file in a strange format:

```
<calendar>
    <event>
        <amount>1200</amount>
        <age>40</age>
        <country>FR</country>

        <amount>255</amount>
        <age>16</age>
        <country>UK</country>

        <amount>10524</amount>
        <age>18</age>
        <country>FR</country>

        <amount>45</amount>
        <age>12</age>
        <country>CH</country>
    <event>
    <event>
        <amount>1540</amount>
        <age>25</age>
        <country>UK</country>

        <amount>255</amount>
        <age>31</age>
        <country>CH</country>

        <amount>4310</amount>
        <age>33</age>
        <country>FR</country>

        <amount>45</amount>
        <age>17</age>
        <country>FR</country>
    <event>
</calendar>
```

From this file I want to compute the sum of every `<amount>` element value, where `<age>` is greater than '20' and `<country>` is either 'FR' or 'CH'.

This operation is independent of the tag `<event>` (all `<amount>` elements that check the above conditions should be summed, whether they're under the same or different `<event>` elements).

My problem is that I have no element tag that groups `<amount>`, `<age>` and `<country>` together... (I can't change the XML format, I'm consuming it from a Web Service I can't access).

If I had an hypothetical `<transfer>` tag grouping these triples together, I think the code would be simply:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("calendar.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> sum =
    from trf in root.Elements("events").Elements("transfers")
    where (decimal) trf.Element("age") > 20 &&
          ((string) trf.Element("Country") == "FR" ||
       (string) trf.Element("Country") == "cH")
    select trf.Element("Amount").Sum();
```

Should I programatically group these elements? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xe = XElement.Load(@"calendar.xml");
var langs = new List<string> { "FR", "CH" };

var sum = xe.Descendants("amount")
    .Where(e =>
           Convert.ToInt32(e.ElementsAfterSelf("age").First().Value) > 20 &&
           langs.Any(l => l == e.ElementsAfterSelf("country").First().Value))
    .Select(e => Convert.ToDouble(e.Value)).Sum();
```

I have tested the code. You also have to make sure that **amount** element must be the first element in the group.

Comment: Thanks, I am unable to check this today, looks good. The usage of "Any()" is particularly relevant (I may have to deal with more langs), I may switch from Xpath to this solution. Will report when I test it.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would just pre-process the Xml (maybe reading it node by node with a [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) ) and read it in a more hierarchical structure. 
That would make it easier to search for elements and also to sort or filter them without losing their relationship (which is now based solely on their order).

**EDIT (see discussion in the comments)**
<strike>As far as I know, the xml specification does not say that the order of the elements is significant, so the parsers you use (or any pre-processing of the Xml as a whole or extraction of its elements) could change the order of amount, age and country elements at the same level.</strike>

While I think most operations tend to preserve the document order, the possibility of subtle and hard-to-find bugs due to random reorderings would not let me sleep too well...

Comment: Thw "warning" is absolutely groundless. The order of elements does matter in XML! -1.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I got the information from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleord/index.html)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: Even this source quotes the appropriate W3C specification" "The XML Information Set (InfoSet -- see Resources), the core XML data model defined by the W3C, characterizes element children as:

**An ordered list of child information items, in document order**. " XPath (and XSLT uses XPath) uses exactly the XML Infoset built from an XML document.

Comment: Right, if ordering didn't matter (or wasn't preserved) then concepts like "preceding" and "following" would be meaningless.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: the whole point of the article I've sent is that XML does NOT specify an ordering for the elements, but that technologies that build on XML (such as XPATH) "do specify some ordering rules for elements, and the order imposed is almost universally document order". Your answer based on XPATH is indeed correct (and I have upvoted it), since XPATH does consider the order of the elements. I am editing my answer, however, because I agree that my worries about the order are very unlikely to be a problem in real code.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: That's great. I have reverted my downvote. More importantly, we have achieved much more here, by realizing that a statement was to a large extent a misconception. I believe that such development is one of the major benefits from Q & A forums like SO.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I'm not sure how you would accomplish that in LINQ, but here's an XPath query that works for me on the data you provided:

**Edit:**

1. returns nodes:

   ```
   //*[text()='FR' or text()='CH']/preceding::age[number(text())>20][1]/preceding::amount[1]
   ```
2. returns sum:

   ```
   sum(//*[text()='FR' or text()='CH']/preceding::age[number(text())>20][1]/preceding::amount[1]/text())
   ```

Comment: hi thanks, this works for the example I gave, but maybe I provided an example that was too simple. if there are more elements between <amount> and <country>, and if 'FR' and 'CH' and numbered values occur in other tags (that may be in the file but I don't care for), this would not make the sum correctly

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a more complete example?

Comment: <address> elements may (or may not) appear before <country> as well as other elements, the code you provided works for the first part, filtering by country, but the >20 condition should be on the <age>, not on the amount. I am having a little trouble improving from your the code because I am new to xpath but it seems to be close to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't read carefully.  One minute and I'll fix it for you...

Comment: Yup, it works. I did some tests with larger files with more tags and I think this is working. I tweaked your solution a bit in order to get the first element before applying each filter, like this: //country[text()='FR' or text()='CH']/preceding::age[1][number(text())>20]/preceding::amount[1]

Comment: The expressions are wrong and the sum that is produced:  12475, is also wrong. -1.

Comment: @Anders: your approach also works, there is just a minor issue that produces the different results: apply the "first" operator (i.e. [1]) before the filtering condition (i.e.[number(text())>20]). I picked the other answer because I prefer LINQ.

Comment: @Ren85: no worries, it's cool. I'm just wondering how Dimitre came up with his numbers - it would have been much more useful to point out and correct the error than just say "you're wrong" and downvote. It seemed rude and rather juvenile.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
sum(/*/*/amount
      [following-sibling::age[1] > 20
     and
       contains('FRCH',
                following-sibling::country[1])
      ])
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "sum(/*/*/amount
          [following-sibling::age[1] > 20
         and
           contains('FRCH',
                    following-sibling::country[1])
          ])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<calendar>
    <event>
        <amount>1200</amount>
        <age>40</age>
        <country>FR</country>
        <amount>255</amount>
        <age>16</age>
        <country>UK</country>
        <amount>10524</amount>
        <age>18</age>
        <country>FR</country>
        <amount>45</amount>
        <age>12</age>
        <country>CH</country>
    </event>
    <event>
        <amount>1540</amount>
        <age>25</age>
        <country>UK</country>
        <amount>255</amount>
        <age>31</age>
        <country>CH</country>
        <amount>4310</amount>
        <age>33</age>
        <country>FR</country>
        <amount>45</amount>
        <age>17</age>
        <country>FR</country>
    </event>
</calendar>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the wanted, correct result is output**:

```
5765
```

**Do note**: **The currently selected answer contains wrong XPath expressions and the sum they produce is wrong**. See this illustrated in the XSLT transformation below (the first number is the correct result, the second number is produced using the XPath expressions from the accepted answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "sum(/*/*/amount
          [following-sibling::age[1] > 20
         and
           contains('FRCH',
                    following-sibling::country[1])
          ])"/>

============
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(//*[text()='FR' or text()='CH']/preceding::age[number(text())>20][1]/preceding::amount[1]/text())"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
5765

============
  12475
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, the XPath solution posted before was in fact incomplete. I am using the LINQ to XML solution at the moment. Are there performance gains in using XSL transformation instead? (working in C# .Net 4.0)

Comment: @Ren85: you are welcome. I haven't compared LINQ to XSLT for performance and I don't even think such comparison could be correctly defined. As always, just using a technology isn't as important as selecting the best algorithm. Programs written in assembler have been shown that run many times slower than program written in Basic -- just because the former implement less efficient algorithms.